# How to create findBy query with multiple contains with just 1 argument

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

I have Repository. And

```
@Repository
public interface CounterpartyRepository extends JpaRepository<Counterparty, Long> {
Page<Counterparty> findByLabelRuContainsOrLabelKzContainsOrLabelEnContainsAllIgnoreCase(String text1, String text2, String text3, Pageable pageable);
}
```

As you can see i have arguments text1, text2, text3. However in my Service i pass same argument to all of them like:

```
repository.findByLabelRuContainsOrLabelKzContainsOrLabelEnContainsAllIgnoreCase(searchText, searchText, searchText, paging);
```

So, how can i create a query which accepts only 1 argument exept Pageable. Thanks)

Answer (score 2):

You could try making a helper method which takes the two parameters that you want and then feeds them into the query:

```
Page<Counterparty> runQuery(searchText, paging){
    return repository.findByLabelRuContainsOrLabelKzContainsOrLabelEnContainsAllIgnoreCase(searchText, searchText, searchText, paging);
}
```